# Bruteforce download and convert images

Tags: bash, wget, image-processing

So, I'm basically trying to brute-force download from a server that doesn't seem to support directory listing or FTP. I know the image files are all png and have numeric filenames ranging from 0-500. Now, here's where things get tricky.

Basically, I need a script to create 3 directories, in the first it uses `wget` to download all the images, not overwriting any of them. (The server has several URLs I need to download from.) Then it uses `imagemagick` to crop the image borders and store them in the second directory, then it uses imagemagick again to convert all the images to a 48x48 ico without stretching the image or affecting quality. I also need to create 2 copies of the icon file, one of which is flipped horizontally and has the letter `f` at the end of the filename.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure it is. Please [edit] your question and show us the commands you have so far. What part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: Keep in mind also by the way bruteforce-download attempting can cause headaches, and you may end up blocked by the server hosts if you are constantly trying

Comment: @terdon I need help with the commands

Comment: Feel free to start a [bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Open the web site with a browser and use a download tool like DownThemAll; or read `man bash`, `man seq`, `man xargs` and `man wget`

Comment: @user245115 well, we're not a free script writing service. I assume you know how to do some of this, right? How to create the directories, say, or how to download the files. You mention imagemagick, do you have the command for that? Have you tried anything? Show us what you have and we can help.

Comment: Here's my current code: https://db.tt/jfB2Cesz